# OpenShift : Access Remote to MySQL on a DIY app without port-forward possible?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

Here the situation, i have an application hosted in a server (call Server A) that need to access to MySQL hosted in a DIY application on OpenShift (Server B).

When the server A try to access to MYSQL i have the following issue :

`[ERROR] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.): Connection refused`

in a local way, if I use the `rhc port-forward` it works. But, I'm not allowed to install `rhc` command line on the server.

Is there a way to configure one of the two servers to access the database ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the DIY cart can't scale you won't be able to access the database externally. When running an embedded mysql cart your mysql instance is going to listen on a 3306 and since that port isn't available externally, you won't be able to connect to it. However, If you had your Server B application running in a scalable gear. Then your mysql cart would be created in its own gear, thus having an external port to listen on.